# Is time period for rajaswala fixed for all women?

Tags: scripture, women, menstruation

Every women becomes Rajaswala and in that time period, there are some rules in Hinduism to follow.

According to scriptures,

Is the time period fixed for all women?

Or

Vary from 3 days to (approximately) a week  based on the women?

Comment: there are rules for what on the 4th day (bathe, but don't cook or go to temple), 5th day (resume normal activities), so the rules are made with the general notion that 3 days is the period of menses, which is the case for most women. But in practice, both the duration, and the cycle (normal is 27 days, similar to moon's revolution around earth), vary for women. I'm not sure if the rules vary, but if I had to take a guess, you have to wait until the flow stops before you can resume activities.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is fixed at 3 days. It does not vary under any circumstances. The 4th day is the day to take bath and from the 5th day on wards religious activities etc. can be resumed. This is what is mentioned in the Smriti scriptures.

If discharge continues to happen even after the period (of 3 days) is over, then that does not create any impurity.

This will be clear from the following verses:

> 15. A woman in her monthly courses, is restored to purity after having washed herself, on the fourth day. When the courses actually cease,
>     however, it is then that she should engage herself in the performance
>     of the rites due to the manes and the gods.
> 16. **When the menstrual fluid flows from day to day on account of a disease, it causes no impurity;** that is, uncleanness by reason of
>     disease alone.
>
> **Parashara Smriti, Chapter 7.**

Comment: Can a man do rituals if his body/clothes are stained by blood ? If not, I assume the same holds for women too ?

Comment: In case of men, it will happen if there is an oozing wound. It's called "kshata ashaucha" or "impurity due to an oozing wound". But in kshata ashaucha men are allowed to perform Nitya Karma at least. I know scriptural evidence for that. Not sure what the instruction will be for women. @ram

Comment: @rickross "When the courses actually cease, however, it is then that she should engage herself in the performance". Does this mean if bleeding continues to day 4 or 5, still considered impure? The second paragraph you added is exception if it's due to disease but not normal times. And, where does it say ritual purity only after 5th day bath?

Comment: If bleeding continues even after 3 days then she is not impure for period but that impurity is simply due to the fact that blood is constantly coming in touch with the skin. It's the same as the impurity related to some wound. Verse 16 is the key to my answer. Ritual purity is attained after the 4th day bath only. @SHebbar