# Can a women take her head bath on Sunday at the end of her menstruation cycle?

Tags: scripture, women, surya, menstruation

According to [scriptures](http://hindupedia.com/en/Surya_ashtakam) one should not take head bath(hair wash) on Sunday

> One who forsakes on all Sundays, Woman oil bath, meat and drinks, Will
> never be sick nor sad nor poor. And would reach the land of sun after
> death.

Assume that a women is following the above and if Sunday is the day she has to take head bath(hair wash) for the reason of completing her menstruation cycle(i.e., on 4th day).

In this situation what a women has to follow?

Comment: It is talking about oil bath (abhayanga snana) and not head bath. The morning bath is compulsory for anyone.Prohibition is regarding oil bath only.

Comment: The Sanskrit verse says "Stri taila madhu mamsani..." taila refers to oil bath.

Comment: @Rickross Menstruating women are disallowed from taking daily bath. For brahmin women, they take a head bath on the 4th day after which they can intermingle with the family but cannot cook / worship. On the 5th day they take another head bath and no longer carry the taint. I will get back with the source but one of the Dharma sastras says that a menstruating woman who takes bath accumulates brahma hatya doSha.

Comment: @hashable Yes I [know that](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/40927/4732). OP is asking if the 4th day happens to be a Sunday is it ok to take bath on that day or not. He is not asking about bathing within 3 days.

Comment: @hashable also you may see this answer: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/43024/4732

Comment: @Rickross My comment was because in the comment above, you have said that the morning bath is "compulsory for anyone". I am just saying that "anyone" doesn't include menstruating women.

Comment: It is clear from the Q itself that its not asking about a menstruating women that's why my statement "morning bath is compulsory for everyone" is valid @hashable

Comment: @Rickross  Here I suppose that head bath means, oiling the hair(May be on that day or on the previous day) and taking the bath(which includes hair wash).

Comment: A simple head bath is not prohibited. What is prohibited is to take oil massage on Sundays. And, after oil massage one has to take bath because oil massage renders the body impure. So, the prohibition you're concerned about is only about having oil massage on Sundays.@satya

Comment: @Rickross Assume that oiling to hair is done on Saturday and head bath(hair wash) is done on Sunday. Is it allowed.

Comment: From [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/43024/4732) --- "A menstruating woman remains impure for three days.  She should not apply collyrium on her eyes or **oil on her body**  @satya

Comment: In this case, Saturday happens to be the 3rd day of the period and on that day she isn't supposed to bath or take oil massage.@satya